# Realm created_at & updated_at timestamps

Tags: swift, swift3, realm

I want to implement 2 timestamps into my Realm objects `created_at` and `updated_at`.

`created_at` would only ever be set once when the object is first inserted into the database.

`updated_at` would store a new timestamp each time the object is modified and saved.

The only way i've found I could do this, is too use the Repository Pattern, with a `create` and `update` function, which would then set the timestamps. However adopting this pattern means refactoring quite a lot of code.

From what I can tell Realm objects do not have any sort of hooks such as `beforeSave` & `afterSave` that I could implement on the object models themselves, which would have been a useful alternative.

Apart from the repository pattern, or manually updating the timestamps before any `realm.write`'s throughout my application, are there any other ways that I could accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two methods provided by `Realm` to achieve what you are looking for.

The first method is [Key-Value Observation](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#key-value-observation), which implements a widely used design pattern with the same name. See [Apple's documentation on the topic](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html).

The second method is `Realm`s own alternative, called [Notifications](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#notifications). You can get notifications about each write transaction to a specific `Realm` instance and handle the ones you need to handle or you can register for notifications about [single Objects](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#object-notifications).

You can use both methods to update the `updated_at` property of your `Realm` objects when you observe/get notified about an update to your object. Handling the `created_at` property is even easier, you just have to set it up to an immutable value at the initialization of your object or you can even do it automatically inside the objects initializer function.

Comment: Thanks for your response David (again). If i had a centralised "TimestampManager" that just managed every single model that may be a good idea.

I did consider a Date on init for the `created_at`, but then I worked out that it only worked if you fetch and save an object rather than using the update option of `realm.add`. If you "fetch & save" the date will not change once it's set, however with `realm.add(obj, update:true)`, that `created_at` becomes an `updated_at` instead, which i felt was flakey... I'll give the notifications a go :)